# How to save, lock, or export my Visual Studio tool panels arrangement?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

The Visual Studio interface is highly configurable, as far as the placement of various tool panels, etc.

But I guess I'm rather clumsy, because I find myself frequently screwing up my panel layout while simply trying to navigate the IDE (dragging a tab instead of clicking, etc).

After getting my panels arranged how I want them, is there any way to lock or save the layout, "set as default", export or otherwise preserve my panel layout preferences?

Clearly this information is being saved somewhere, because if I close and restart Visual Studio my current panel arrangement is saved. At the very least, is there some "unsupported" way to access this internal config and reload/reset my preferred state?

Comment: I'm not in front of VS2012, but on VS2008, there's a "Import and Export Settings" menu item in the Tools menu that will let you save/export your settings. Have a look at that.
I don't think there is a "lock"; but I wish it existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has some pretty granular support for exporting your settings.  For window placement, follow these steps:

1. Go to Tools -> Import and Export Settings
2. Export settings
3. Make sure All Settings -> General Settings -> Window Layouts is checked (you can check or uncheck whatever else you want)
4. Click Next and save your settings file
5. Import the settings on your other machine (or on the same one to restore)

Comment: I sure wish there was a "lock panels" option, but I believe this answers my question.